# XAML Textblock Tapped event not firing inside ItemsControl DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="nodeTrafficQualifierTemplate">
        <Grid Width="400" Margin="8">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <TextBlock Name="GreenQualifier"  Text="{StaticResource CircleOpen}" 
                       IsTapEnabled="True"
                       Tapped="TrafficLightQualifier_OnTapped"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" 
                       FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,60,0" Foreground="Green"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

private void TrafficLightQualifier_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Never get here...
        var qualifier = ((TextBlock)sender).Name;
        switch (qualifier)
        {
            case "GreenQualifier":

                break;
        }
    }
```

The event handler simply never gets called. I had pretty much the same thing as this except using Image control instead of Textblock, and the Tapped event handler worked fine.

The Loaded event for the Textblock fires and is handled without problems.

Is this related to focus? Is there any way to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Well this is getting pretty weird. When I use the following glyph:

&#xE080;

It doesn't fire (that's a filled circle from Symbol font)

However almost all other glyphs DO work (the event handler works).

Something about the type of glyph is causing problems. Maybe shifting the hit zone somehow (these are "zero width" glyphs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it works fine.

But, one assumption is that, `ListView` or where your `DataTemplate` is consumed handles `Tapped` event before eventhandler. Check your `ListView` attributes and mine.

My ListView is as below. You can find `<!-- THIS IS WHERE I TESTED -->` code.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ListViewPages" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{StaticResource LbLightShadowBrush}"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,45,0,0"
        CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" SelectionChanged="ListViewPages_OnSelectionChanged">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Height="60">
                                    <Grid Background="White">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="TestBlock" Foreground="{StaticResource LbBackgroundBrush}" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Margin="0,3" Tapped="TestBlock_OnTapped" /> <!-- THIS IS WHERE I TESTED -->
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource LbLightTextBrush}" Text="{Binding Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource PropertyDataSummary}}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

And, eventhandler is simply checked by breakpoint.

```
        private void TestBlock_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("tapped");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... Can't see how my code is different, but obviously something is going on. I'll keep experimenting. Thanks for confirming that it is possible Youngjae.

Comment: @SteveMacdonald // As you can see, `DataTemplate` in my code is inlined in `ListView`. If your `DataTemplate` is outside of it, try it with inlined manner. Logically it would be same, but who knows...?

Answer (score 2):

This was definitely an edge case. The symbols I was using as the text in my Textbloxk are "zero width" glyphs designed to overlay each other to make radio buttons etc. Most of the Symbol glyphs are not zero-width and they worked fine. The solution was to add a Width="40" to the Textblock and then the event handler worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the handler in the constructor in the code behind:

```
GreenQualifier.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(TrafficLightQualifier_OnTapped), true);
```